# Concept of changing a user's email

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a question about the very concept of changing a user's email. It's just a concept without code.

When the user wants to change email, he goes to settings and click button "Send a link to change email". After that I am sending a message to user's email which contains link with a token to change email. Link looks like this: `{{domain}}/new-email/{{uid}}/{{token}}`. On this page user can put the new email and now here is my question:

I need to send another message to the new mail with a link to check if that new mail is real.
My user model contains just current `email` field. I need to remember somewhere the new mail so after user click the activation link inside message, the `email` field will be replaced by the new mail. Where should I store the new mail? Should I create a new field inside user model (replace `email` by `current_email` and add `new_email`) and after user click the activation link the `current_email` will be replaced by the `new_email` value and `new_email` will be set to null again? Or maybe should I store the new mail inside token (which will be inside the activation link URL) without creating the new field inside user model?

Which option will be safer and cleaner?

I am using Django and React.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend creating a new field.

You can use the token option or store the new email in the cache. Use the id value of the user (or any unique identifier value) whose email address you want to change and the new email address as key, value pair.

Comment: Thank You, but why You don't recommend creating a new field?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).